# Expression regular for password

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I need the correct regular expression pattern, for checking input text in HTML matching this format:

- Start with a capital letter
- End with the character $
- Between the initial capital letter and the final dollar character there may be:

  1. Letter between a and z (both included) uppercase or lowercase
  2. Digit from zero to nine (two included)
  3. The underscore character ( _ )

Example: `B4rc3l0nA$, Fr4_nc3$, A$`

I think I have to add anchors at the beginning and at the end, but I don't know how to join everything so that the complete regular expression remains.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Your password" pattern="^\[a-z]i\s-\s[0-9]{2}\([a-z]{1,3})$" required>
```

Comment: Instead, it's _far_ easier to allow "any text whatsoever" (because it's not the 1990s anymore, utf-8 data is trivially transmitted between front and backend) and then at the backend you hash the (salted) password and work with that instead. There is zero reason to have any password restrictions in 2022 other than "your password isn't long enough, it takes mere seconds to crack" to force your users to pick a secure password. Forcing passwords to follow a pattern does the exact opposite of making them more secure. Just use a password strength checker with arbitrary text input allowed.

Comment: What Mina posted below. But evaluating or having a regexp evaluation in a frontend in a tag is probably a bad idea. It's trivially simple to manipulate or circumvent. You should at least have a check in the background.  You should also specify what "A capital letter" means.  Å, Ø and Ü are all capital letters.

Comment: Why are you matching `\s-\s` ? Should the 2 digits be right next to each other?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regular expression.

```
^[A-Z]\w+?\$$
```

1. `^[A-Z]` meaning start with capital character as first letter.
2. `\w+?` any letter or number or underscore
3. `\$$` dollar sign at the end.

```js
const checkPassword = (password) => {
  return /^[A-Z]\w+?\$$/.test(password)
}


console.log(checkPassword("B4rc3l0nA$"))
console.log(checkPassword("Fr4_nc3$"))
console.log(checkPassword("Fr4_nc3"))
console.log(checkPassword("fr4_nc3$"))
console.log(checkPassword("Ab!!@@ÅÆØ}$"))
```

[FOR TESTING](https://regex101.com/r/yMKDoo/1)

Comment: Should probably be `^[A-Z]\w+?\$$`, else only first position is as required.  With the `^[A-Z]\w.+?\$$` regexp, also `Ab!!@@ÅÆØ}$` is valid.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to remove the `dot` thanks for notifying me.

Comment: This part `\w+?` does not have to be non greedy as the `\w` does not match `$`